# Algorithm to reverse list items in place?

Tags: python, reverse

I'm learning about data structures and algorithm efficiency in my CS class right now, and I've created an algorithm to return a new list of items that in reverse order from the original list.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this in place with Python lists using recursion, but the solution is eluding me.  Here is my code:

```
def reverse_list(in_list):
    n = len(in_list)
    print('List is: ', in_list)
    if n <= 2:
        in_list[0], in_list[-1] = in_list[-1], in_list[0]
        return in_list
    else:
        first = [in_list[0]]
        last = [in_list[-1]]
        temp = reverse_list(in_list[1:-1])
        in_list = last + temp + first
        print('Now list is: ', in_list)
        return in_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = list(range(1, 12))
    list2 = reverse_list(list1)
    print(list2)
```

As a side note, this is O(n) in average case due to it being n/2 right?

Comment: `in_list[1:-1]` is in O(N), so the algorithm is in O(N²). The term "average case" does not apply, there is no best nor worst case in here.

Comment: Could you explain a little further to help me understand?  Thanks:)

Comment: Well, you are doing N/2 = O(N) operations, each costing O(N). O(N) * O(N) = O(N^2). Btw. I like the idea of your algorithm. The only problem is that slicing in Python creates a copy and Python is not tail recursive. You could say that this is a shortcoming of Python, not of your algorithm.

Comment: I think the op may have been referring to `.reverse` as an "average case". If so, I believe pythons reverse function does operate at O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `n <= 2` case is good. It is "in-place" in both of the usual senses. It modifies the same list as is passed in, and it only uses a constant amount of memory in addition to the list passed in.

Your general case is where you have problems. It uses a lot of extra memory (n/2 levels of recursion, each of which holds two lists across the recursive call, so all those lists at all levels have to exist at once), and it does not modify the list passed in (rather, it returns a new list).

I don't want to do too much for you, but the key to solving this is to pass one (or two if you prefer) extra parameter(s) into the recursive step. Either an optional parameter to your function, or define a recursive helper function that has them. Use this to indicate *what region* of the list to reverse in-place.

As someone mentioned in comments, CPython doesn't have a tail-recursion optimization. This means that no algorithm that uses call-recursion like this is ever going to be truly "in-place", since it will use linear amounts of stack. But "in-place" in the sense of "modifies the original list instead of returning a new one" is certainly doable.

Comment: I was thinking about this, create a first_index and last_index that would move each time so I could keep the same list.  Is this more or less the track you're talking about?

Comment: @flybonzai: that's the one! In these exercises, "use recursion" usually means, "find a way to take an instance of the problem, and turn it into a slightly smaller instance of the same problem".

Answer (score 4):

You really don't want to be using recursion here as it doesn't really simplify the problem for the extra overhead involved with the function calls:

```
list3 = list(range(1, 10))
for i in range(len(list3)/2):
    list3[i], list3[len(list3)-i-1] = list3[len(list3)-i-1], list3[i]
print(list3)
```

if you wanted to approach it using recursion, you'd pass in an index counter to each call of your function till you had gotten half way through the list. This would give you O(n/2) runtime.